# Is a javascript file XSS safe?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, xss

I was asked to correct an XSS vulnerability on an old site web, using jsp and javascript.

On a "Return" button, I would put a "backURL" parameter as a href, to be able to go back to the previous page I was on.

Previously, my javascript code was in the HTML page, which would make it exploitable by replacing the parameter with a script.

I came up with 2 "Solutions" and I wanted to ask if they were valid.

First, I would encode the URL when getting the parameter in the javascript function, using this library: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project

Here's the code in my jsp file:

```
<a class="float_left button" href="#" onclick="goback(this)" >Retour</a>
```

Then right under it, in the same file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function goback(domEle) {
        var backUrl = "${e:forHtml(param.backUrl)}";
        domEle.href= decodeEntity(backUrl);
    }

    function decodeEntity(str){
       return str.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
    }
```

But then, I thought that it would maybe work to just put this javascript in another file, doing like this:

JSP file:

```
<a class="float_left button" href="#" onclick="goback(this,'${param.backUrl}')" >Retour</a>
```

javascript file:

```
function goback(domEle,backUrl) {
        domEle.href= backUrl;
    }
```

From my tests, both seem to work.
But I wanted to know if it was really completely XSS proof, and if it is which one is the best way to do.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why are you setting the `href` via JavaScript to begin with? You already know that the `href` is going to be `param.backUrl`, so why not immediately set the `href` attribute to that value? (After encoding it of course.)

Comment: @Ivar That's a pretty good question. It was like this when I got the code, so I believe it was used for something else before. I changed it to `<a class="float_left button" href="${e:forHtml(param.backUrl)}">Retour</a> `. Is that safe ?

Comment: I'd use `e:forHtmlAttribute(param.backUrl)`, since you are adding the value as an attribute. That should be enough.

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot !